# Как передать ID строки в модал?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap

У меня есть таблица, заполняю из Базы данных. У каждой строки есть кнопка Edit, которая открывает модальную форму. Как передать ID нажатой строки Edit-а, что бы при помощи sql заполнить модал?

Вот мой код. Мне нужно получаить $id, а не результат в классе, так как буду использовать в sql.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">          
  <table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="header">
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Müştərinin Nömrəsi</th>
        <th>Götürülən Ünvan</th>
        <th>Gədilən Ünvan</th>
        <th>Zəng Vaxtı</th>
        <th>Sürücünün Tabel Kod</th>
        <th>Təhfil aldı</th>
        <th>Təhfil verdi</th>
        <th>Maşın Nömrəsi</th>
        <th>Qiymət</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php


while($data=mysql_fetch_array($result)) // цикл вывода
{
 $id = $data['id'];

     
  echo "<tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>".$data['MUSHTERINOMRE']."</td>
        <td>".$data['MUSHTERIHARDAN']."</td>
        <td>".$data['MUSHTERIHARA']."</td>
        <td>".$data['ZENGVAXTI']."</td>
        <td>".$data['TABELKOD']."</td>
        <td>".$data['TEHFILALDI']."</td>
        <td>".$data['TEHFILVERDI']."</td>
        <td>".$data['MASHINNOMRE']."</td>
        <td>".$data['QIYMET']."</td>
        <td><button class=\"btn btn-success\" onclick='getValue(".$id.");' data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" contenteditable=\false\" value=".$id.">EDIT </button></td>
  "; ?>
            
      </tr>
   
   <?php
}
   ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="">?   </span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>

                </button>

                <!--Here I am trying to echo ID
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><?php //echo $id."ID OFaa"; ?></h4>-->

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
   <?php echo $id."I NEED TO GET ID HERE "; ?>
   <?php 
     $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'psw');
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('my_db', $link);

   $query = mysql_query("Select * from my_table where id = $id");
   //var_dump($pt);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   $number = $row['num'];
   ?>
         <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name" class="control-label">Müştəri Nömrə:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="num" name="num" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                  </div>
   
   
   
   
   </div>
   
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: так вы как предполагаете это сделать у вас не получится. Контент диалогового окна надо запрашивать `ajax`-ом. То есть один php-файл у вас рисует таблицу с кнопкой, и оберткой диалога. На странице вы жмете кнопку, берете id, и отправляете ajax-запрос второму php-файлу. А этот второй пхп файл генерирует нужное представление по полученному id, которое вы вставляете внутрь диалога, и потом его показываете.

Comment: @teran Спасибо за ответ. Можете помочь сделать это на на моем примере? А то я пытался по разному, но не работает у меня. Могу передавать в дивку в модал, но не могу передать ID как  переменную, что бы использовать в sql.